# How to filter an array of object in Vuejs typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In this project. I'm using Vuejs Typescript and the data type is like:

```
["order":
  {
    "id":1,
    "created_at":"2019-12-06T10:22:17Z",
    "status":"open",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-27T04:21:06Z",
    "recipient":null,
    "custom_fields":[
      {"id":2,"value":'ABC'},
      {"id":3,"value":'EFG},
      {"id":4,"value":'CSA'}
    ]
  }
]
```

This is how I get the data:

```
private mapUnprinted (data: any) : IUnprintedSet {
    const result: IUnprintedSet = { orders: [], pagination: {} }
    if (data) {
      data.forEach((anUnprinted: any) => {
        const order: IUnprinted = {
          id: anUnprinted.id,
          created_at: anUnprinted.created_at,
          status: anUnprinted.status,
          updated_at: anUnprinted.updated_at,
          recipient: anUnprinted.recipient,
          custom_fields:  anUnprinted.custom_fields
          // filter((item: any) => item.custom_fields.id === '3'),
        }
        result.orders!.push(order);
      })
      result.pagination = {
        currentPage: data.pagination ? data.pagination.currentPage : undefined,
        pageSize: data.pagination ? data.pagination.pageSize : undefined,
        totalPages: data.pagination ? data.pagination.totalPages : undefined,
        totalResults: data.pagination? data.pagination.totalResults : result.orders!.length
      }
    }
    return result
  }
```

I added

```
filter((item: any) => item.custom_fields.id === '3'),
```

But seems like its not working. End up it return me empty array.
The whole issue is i wanna get the value from custom_fields where the ID is equal to 3

This is the return custom_fields:

```
anUnprinted.custom_fields.filter((item: any) => item.id === '3'),
```

```
"order": {
      "id": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-12-06T10:22:17Z",
      "status": "open",
      "updated_at": "2020-07-27T04:21:06Z",
      "recipient": null,
      "custom_fields": []
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to have a property called `filter` which is a function on a type called `IUnprinted`?

Comment: Yes i wanna use .filter and I added .filter((item: any) => item.custom_fields.id === '3') but it return me empty array. And im not sure which part i did it wrong.

Comment: @cSharp I added the outcome after added the filter

Comment: filter isn't called correctly. It should either be called like anUnprinted.custom_fields.filter(anUnprinted), which is awkward, or be declared differently, filter(() => anUnprinted.custom_fields.id === '3') . It's unclear what's the purpose. If custom_fields doesn't change with time, an item could be filtered when forEach runs. custom_fields seems to be incorrectly used. It's shown to be an array but is treated like an object, custom_fields.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` is number not string so maybe:

```
item.id === 3
```

or

```
item.id == '3'
```

Comment: `custom_fields` is an array of objects. Hence, we can not directly access the `id` property.

Comment: @Rohìt Jíndal hey mate, this is only the part when the op is  setting condition for filter

Comment: I think op is doing it wrongly. It should be `item.custom_fields.filter(field => field.id === 3)`

Comment: yes , you are 100% right , my bad, copied wrong part of questions, thanks mate, cheers :)

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT! Yes. I'm able to fixed it already. Thank you so much @RohìtJíndal and Nikola!

Answer (score 1):

Your data type aren't the same, data type in your id used are **number** but inside filter() u checked for **string**

*I'm new here, just trying to improve my skill.Do correct me if I’m wrong*

Comment: YES YES! It is correct. All i did is just changing the item.id === '3' into item.id == '3' Thank you @QwErT